# ORL dataset Pytorch dataset input data

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, dataset, tensor

I am trying to make a neural network in Pytorch to recognize faces from the famous Olivetti faces dataset (ORL dataset). The dimensions of the images are 32x32=**1024**, and there are a total of **400** of them with **40** classes. I transferred the dataset from the .mat file to Python's familiar variable environment.

```
orl = loadmat('ORL_32x32.mat')
x = orl["fea"]
y = orl["gnd"]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df_label = pd.DataFrame(y) 
df.to_csv("data.csv", index = False)
df_label.to_csv("y.csv", index = False)
```

And after that I did the following code

```
label = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(df_label.values) #shape torch.Size([1, 400, 1])
df_tensor = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(df.values)  #shape torch.Size([1, 400, 1024])
```

After that, I created a tensor dataset and started training through epochs.

```
trn = TensorDataset(df_tensor,label)
#print(type(trn))
trn_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trn,batch_size=400,shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

  for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(trn_dataloader):   
         print(data.shape)   #torch.Size([1, 400, 1024])
```

Which is actually a big problem - because data.shape should be torch.Size([1, 1, 1024]) just one image, not the whole dataset looking as one image.
What is the best way to solve the whole problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the batch size of the dataloader to be 400, which you stated is the number of images in the dataset. The `data` tensor in the dataloader loop will therefore contain all images. If you set the batch size to 1, you will see that data will have shape `(1, 1, 1024)`.

Depending on how you are training your model, you will adjust the batch size accordingly, but usually you do not train with 1 as batch size.

Since working with PyTorch, I would advise reshaping your data to the standard way for images, which is `(batch size, number of channels, height, width)`. It seems like you are working with flattened images, so therefore the shape should be `(batch size, number of features)`.

To me it seems like your `data.csv` has some wrong arrangements to be loaded the right way. When loaded, it mixes up the channel and batch size dimensions. But this can be fixed by permutating the tensor:

```
df_tensor = df_tensor.permute(1, 0, 2) # Shape: (1, 400, 1024) -> (400, 1, 1024)
```

Or scrapping the channel dimension since these are flattened images:

```
df_tensor = df_tensor.squeeze(0) # Shape: (1, 400, 1024) -> (400, 1024)
```

Comment: I understand, but let's say if I want to implement a convolutional network. Isn't it then that I want the convolution to be performed on each image separately, and not on the entire dataset or its subset (if batch_size>1)?

Comment: PyTorch handles the batch dimension so that operations will be performed on each instance separately. 

Given a tensor `x` containing 10 grayscale images, with shape `(10, 1, 32, 32)`, a convolutional network that retains channel, width and height dimension will produce a tensor `y` of shape `(10, 1, 32, 32)`. 

If we had performed the same operation on the first element `x[0:1]` we would have got `y[0:1]` (slicing done to retain batch dimension while indexing the first element).